# How do I parse an object from a page to the app.component.ts to another page?

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I parse an object from HomePage to a function in app.component.ts where my side menu is to another Page that will retrieve it using NavParam?

Comment: Normally you would [push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#push) a new page onto the HomePage. The push function accepts `params` which you can then retrieve in the pushed pages NavParams.

Comment: If you do not want to push directly onto the HomePage you can use a service to share data...

Comment: I understand navParams however since my side menu functions are not on my HomePage, I cannot directly use navCtrl to push with params since the function is in my app.component.ts where all my side menu functionality resides. But I will look into services. Many thanks!